# MultipeerConnectivity Pass Thumbnail Before Connecting

Tags: ios, bonjour, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to figure out a way to pass a thumbnail image between devices BEFORE the devices agree to connect.

Therefore I can not use the send data or send resource methods.
I can't pass it in the discoveryInfo as that would go over the discoveryInfo's size limit.

Yes I ***COULD*** store the image on a server and store a link to it in the discoveryInfo and pass that, but that isn't really an option (one for example, think about no internet connection)

The reason for this is I need to show the thumbnail of the user next to their name when they show up in the list.

(I am NOT using the standard peer picker window, but doing my own interface using MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser and MCNearbyServiceBrowser)

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could pass a thumbnail, or pass reference to a thumbnail that I can then have the app on their device then get, via standard controls/Multipeer/Bonjour/etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you hear the nearby peer and invite them to join the session, you call

```
invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout:
```

The context is an "arbitrary piece of data that is passed to the nearby peer. This can be used to provide further information to the user about the nature of the invitation."

Presumably, you can include an NSData that contains a thumbnail image in the context.

You can exchange information at an earlier stage by providing discoveryInfo when creating the MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser. This is a dictionary of key-value pairs that are made available to browsers.  However, you cannot use that for a thumbnail as "The key-value pair must be no longer than 255 bytes (total) when encoded in UTF-8".

To exchange larger amounts of data you need to create a custom discovery class using Bonjour for discovery.

Comment: I think this should work, though unfortunately the reference documents don't indicate an upper bound on this data.  Hopefully your thumbnail is small enough.  Be sure to follow the secure coding guidelines.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002415

Comment: This is when you invite them, I need to be able to have shown the thumbnail before inviting them. This gives the user a better list (better looking but also easier to know who they are inviting)

Comment: If it works for you you can on discoveryInfo set a small string dictionary
   " var discoveryInfo: [String : String]?". It do not say you can pass data with disovery. If you find a method for encode thumbnail as String it can work ... It can impact discovery performance